# Microsoft .Net Native Compiler

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-native

Recently i have been getting the following error on my build agent but not on my local build.
EXEC:EXEC(0,0): Error : Could not find file"C:\Users\*\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.2\tools\x86\ilc\lib\Facades'."

Answer (score 1):

After much research i realized the problem i was having is the "Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler" is a dependency in one of my nugget packages "Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform". The reason that it kept failing was because this dependency can only be compiled in ARM and X64 causing my build to fail when it was building in x86. I resolved this by downgrading my nugget package to the most recent without the "Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler" dependency than my build completed successfully.